# Binomial formula implementation for matrices of different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, binomial-theorem

I am trying to implement (x-y)^2 for two matrices x of dimension n*2 and y of dimension m*2. I think to solve it, we might apply the binomial formula (x-y)^2 = x^2-2x.T*y+y^2=x.T*x-2x.T*y+y.T*y.

My first draft is the following:

```
tmp1 = numpy.square(input1)
tmp2 = numpy.square(input2)
res = numpy.dot(input1, input2.T)
res *= -2
res += temp1.reshape(-1, 1)
res += temp2
return np.exp(res)
```

Unfortunately, I still have problems with the dimensionality of my temporal variables after hours of trying. It would be great to get some further help how to code the binomial formula for different sized matrices.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be clear: both matrices are square, but have different sizes? Can you show us a small example input and work out, by hand, step by step, what the result should be? I'm not convinced that it makes sense to be able to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `x` and `y` are two 1d arrays with different dimensions, and you want the square of their `outer` difference:

```
In [98]: x = np.arange(1,5); y = np.arange(5,8); x,y
Out[98]: (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7]))
```

Your `(x-y)^2` can be easily done with `broadcasting`:

```
In [99]: (x[:,None]-y)**2
Out[99]: 
array([[16, 25, 36],
       [ 9, 16, 25],
       [ 4,  9, 16],
       [ 1,  4,  9]])
```

Or if we make:

```
In [100]: x1 = x[:,None]       # (4,1) shape
In [101]: (x1-y)**2
Out[101]: 
array([[16, 25, 36],
       [ 9, 16, 25],
       [ 4,  9, 16],
       [ 1,  4,  9]])
```

then your binomial formula is:

```
In [103]: x1**2 - 2*x1*y+y**2
Out[103]: 
array([[16, 25, 36],
       [ 9, 16, 25],
       [ 4,  9, 16],
       [ 1,  4,  9]])
```

`x` is 1d, so `x.T` doesn't change anything.  What I think you were aiming for was transposing a (1,4) to (4,1).

If the arrays are different, say 2d, you'll need to give a clear example.

If the arrays are "row vectors", these are equivalent:

```
In [105]: x.shape, y.shape
Out[105]: ((1, 4), (1, 3))
In [106]: (x.T-y)**2
...
In [107]: x.T**2 - 2*x.T*y + y**2
```

### edit

Looking for 'binomial forumala matrices' I found:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754278/binomial-formula-for-matrices

This talks a lot about whether the matrices are comutative, etc.

What I've shown is how to apply the basic scalar binomial formula element-wise to arrays.  The (m,) and (n,) shaped arrays are (effectively) expanded to (m,n), and the formula is applied elementwise.  The basic operator, '+-*' all apply elementwise, enhanced with `broadcasting`.

What's unclear in your question and comments is what `x^2`, `x.Tx` and `x.Ty` mean when `x` and `y` are 2d.  Which are matrix multiplication, written in `numpy` with `np.dot` or `@` (`np.matmul`)?

Matrix multiplication has specific rules about how dimensions combine. A (3,2) @ (2,4) => (3,4), while a (2,4) @ (3,2) produces an error.

And (3,2) cannot be +/- with a (4,2).  It is possible to expand the dimensions and produce a (3,4,2) 'outer' sum or difference.

Comment: Hey,
thanks for this answer. I don't think, that the code works for nx2 and mx2 sized matrices x and y. But I need a solution for different sized matrices unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly do you mean vy `nx2`?  (n,n) shape?  What would be the shape of the result?  I showed that with (n,) and (m,) shapes the result is (n,m)